# Fake proof: All spaces are homotopically equivalent

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, fake-proofs

The definition of homotopy equivalence in Munkre's book:
[image]

An exercise from the same book:

[image]

**My problem with this:**

If all functions are homotopic, doesn't that mean that all spaces are homotopically equivalent?! In fact we get $g\circ f\simeq i_X$ and $f\circ g\simeq i_Y$ whatever functions $f,g$ we choose, and looking at the definition this means that $X,Y$ are homotopically equivalent, whatever they are. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: All functions are **not** homotopic: all functions from a given space $X$ to the very particular space $\Bbb R^n$ are homotopic.

Comment: You cannot go from functions being homotopic, which is one idea, especially when $\mathbb R^N$ is the target space (a space with properties such as being simply connected, convex, open etc), to spaces being homotopy equivalent, which is a separate idea, where there is no necessary fixed space with good properties.

Comment: @MarkBennet: If it is true that all pairs of functions $X \to Y$ are homotopic, then it's easy to prove any two nonempty spaces are homotopy equivalent: pick any constant functions $X \to Y$ and $Y \to X$, and they will be homotopy inverses.

Comment: @Hurkyl That was not my point - here there is a fixed space with good properties, which enables the conclusion about functions. $X$ and $Y$ are not arbitrary.

Comment: I would think that continuity of the maps is important, yet that seems left out of the definition for _homotopy equivalent_ above.  Also, if the straight-line homotopy given in equation (*) is required to be continuous, the original functions $f, h$ must also be continuous.

Comment: @Michael I agree: that seems to be missing from Munkres' book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mistake is that the exercise shows that any two maps to $\mathbb{R^n}$, specifically, are homotopic. It's a property of $\mathbb{R^n}$. What it means for homotopy equivalence is that, when we're trying to show $X$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R^n}$, it suffices to build a the homotopy between our maps on the "$X$" side, since we automatically get one on the $\mathbb{R^n}$ side. A corollary is that $\mathbb{R^m}$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R^n}$ for all $m,n$, which is true.

Answer (score 3):

The result shown in the exercise allows us to show that $\Bbb R^n$ and $\Bbb R^m$ are homotopy equivalent, but cannot be applied in the general case:
If we let $X=\Bbb R^n$ and $Y=\Bbb R^m$, it is easy to come up with *some* continuous (e.g., constant) maps $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Y\to X$. Then the continuous maps $g\circ f\colon X\to X=\Bbb R^n$ and $i_X$ are continuous maps form some space $X$ to $\Bbb R^n$, and by the exercise are homotopic. The same holds for $f\circ g$ and $i_Y$, as the exercise applies also to $Y=\Bbb R^m$.
*However,* this trick wonÄt work if either of $X,Y$ is not some $\Bbb R^{\text{something}}$ ...